# Relative topologies from induced metrics.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Question: Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $Y \subseteq X$. The restriction $d_Y$ of $d$ to $Y \times Y$ yields a metric on $Y$, which we shall call the induced metric on $Y$. Prove that the metric topology on $Y$ resulting from $d_Y$ coincides with the relative topology on $Y$ as a subspace of $X$ with its metric topology.

Can you please give me a hint as to how I should go about proving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove that $\mathcal{B}:=\{B_d(y,\varepsilon)\cap Y\:;\: y\in Y,\:\varepsilon>0\}$ is a base for the relative topology on $Y$, where $B_d(y,\varepsilon)$ denotes the ball of radious $\varepsilon$ centered at $y$, i.e.

$B_d(y,\varepsilon):=\{ x\in X \:;\: d(x,y)<\varepsilon \}$.

Prove that $B_d(y,\varepsilon)\cap Y=B_{d_Y}(y,\varepsilon)$,

where $B_{d_Y}(y,\varepsilon):=\{ x\in Y \:;\: d_{Y}(x,y)<\varepsilon \}$.